# Make the background-color of div change when the mouse is down and hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, mouseevent

When hovering over a div along with the mouse being constantly held down, I would like the background-color of the div to be changed.

Code:

```
<style>
    #container{
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: aquamarine;

        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let cells=Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('cell'));
        cells.forEach(cell => {
            cell.onmouseover = () => {
                cell.onmousedown = () => {
                    cell.style.backgroundColor="black";
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is that the `div` only turns black on the first click. There is no change on the other `div`'s when the mouse is then subsequently dragged over them while the mouse is constantly being held down. The cursor just turns into a red circle-backslash symbol.

I have tried adding an event (as seen in the code above) where if the element is moved over but only when the mouse is down, it transforms the background-color to black.

Oh, and I'd like to only use vanilla js, not jQuery or any additional extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with the following script. It works on my side

```
<script>
            let cells=Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('cell'));

            let flag = false;
            
            window.onmouseup = () => {                        
                flag = false;
            }
            cells.forEach(cell => {
                cell.onmouseover = () => {
                    if(flag == true)
                    {
                        cell.style.backgroundColor="black";
                    }
                    cell.onmousedown = () => {
                        cell.style.backgroundColor="black";
                        flag = true;
                    }                  

                    
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question, window.mouseup checks if the mouse is being held throughout the entire viewable display...?

Comment: Yeah. correct. you can release your mouse outside of the cells so we should set flag variable as 'false" in that case not only for cell.onmouseup.

Answer (score 1):

A little cleaner code than above one:

```
<script>
    const cells = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('cell'));
    var flag = false; //Here, I think it should be var, not let.
    
    window.onmouseup = () => { flag = false; }

    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.onmouseover = () => { if(flag) cell.style.backgroundColor="black"; }
        cell.onmousedown = () => { cell.style.backgroundColor="black"; flag = true; }                  
    });
</script>
```